как попасть на под внутри Kubernetes внутри Docker?
я столкнулся с проблемой, я создал виртуальную машину с ubuntu, внутри неё установил docker, и внутрь docker засунул Kubernetes, но получить доступа к пода я не могу, запущенные контейнеры
root@serv:/home/user# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                                                                                                                                  NAMES
cccd16c7945d   gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.44   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   5 hours ago   Up 5 hours   127.0.0.1:32768->22/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32769->2376/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32770->5000/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32771->8443/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32772->32443/tcp   minikube

внутри Kubernetes я создало deployment
root@serv:/home/user/hello_web# k get deploy
NAME        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
helloword   1/1     1            1           46m

под который у меня получился в следствии
root@serv:/home/user/hello_web# k get pod
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
helloword-54bcffff49-z2v5x   1/1     Running   0          47m

после чего я создал сервис
k expose deploy helloword --type=NodePort --port=3333 --target-port=3000

сам сервис
root@serv:/home/user# kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
helloword    NodePort    10.110.62.126   <none>        3333:31688/TCP   3h11m
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          5h21m

после создания сервиса я открыл туннель
root@serv:/home/user# minikube tunnel
Status:
        machine: minikube
        pid: 37976
        route: 10.96.0.0/12 -> 192.168.49.2
        minikube: Running
        services: [helloword]
    errors:
                minikube: no errors
                router: no errors
                loadbalancer emulator: no errors

после чего я попытался обратиться к поду  по адресу 192.168.49.2:32473, не нечего не вышло
после чего я попробовал команду
minikube service helloword --url

что она мне вернула
http://192.168.49.2:32473

но нечего не получилось
